# How to send gamepad events to cocos2dx game

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2dx and developing a game for android in which i want to add feature to control player movements with a game controller (gamepad). I have got gamepad events (up, down, left, right, buttons) in my main java activity that extends cocos2dxActivity, But i am unable to send these events to my cocos2dx gameBoardLayer that extends CCLayer. In simple words I want to do:

in MainActivity.java
getGamePadMotionEvent() --> sendtoGameLayerOfcocos2dx()

in GameBoardLayer.cpp (this class extends CCLayer)
recieveGamePadMotionEvents();

Can anybody help me with a piece of code or any link to right direction?